# Radio buttons with HelloSign API

Tags: python, radio-button, electronic-signature, hellosign-api

I'm trying to add a radio button to a template that I am sending through [HelloSign's API](http://www.hellosign.com/api/reference) to be eSigned. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. There documentation mentions checkboxes but not radio buttons. Is there a POST parameter I need to set to turn a checkbox into a radio button? Or am I missing something else?

I feel like I've signed a document before on HelloSign where I used a radio button, but maybe I'm mistaken.

I am using Python, if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

HelloSign does offer radio buttons in the form of "grouped checkboxes" (where a rule is applied, such as "require 1" or "require 2", etc.).

Unfortunately, as of this post, creating grouped checkboxes is not yet supported by the API.

Comment: Hi Chris, is there any suggestion for the same in java

Comment: Or please suggest me how do i implement this functionality using checkboxes